# Setting icon on infowindow of a marker in google map

Tags: android, google-maps

How can I set an information icon (i) in the Infowindow of a customized marker? The infowindow shows when I click on my marker. The infowindow contains the name of the place on which I hav clicked. I want to show the info icon on the right side of the name.
I have the information logo in my drawable folder. Just need to show that in the infowindow.
Any help would be apprreciated!!

Comment: Please check -> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows#custom_info_windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Since, you want to customize the info_window layout, Create a custom layout of your choice of views and position.

mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                                return null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                                View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window,null);

                                tv_Locality.setText( marker.getTitle());

                                tv_Snippet.setText( marker.getSnippet());
                                return view;
                            }
                        });

Refer: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap
```

Comment: In predefined info_window layout, like you mentioned, it will set the MARKER image. It won't set into the info_window. I want the info icon in info_window.

Comment: To have info_icon in info_window, you have to make info window with customized contents. I have edited the answer.